# wrong result of int for large number in python

Tags: python, integer

The result of below in python is `24019198012642644`.

```
print(int((72057594037927936-1)/3))
```

When I calculate it using calculator in Windows is `24019198012642645`.

Below is python version

```
Python 3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Please advise what is wrong with code.

Comment: see also: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `print((72057594037927936-1)//3)` then you will get `24019198012642645`. The other answer is due to float division